# If $A^{1/A}=B^{1/B}=C^{1/C}$, $A^{BC}+B^{AC}+C^{AB}=768$. What is the value of $A^{1/A}$?

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, exponentiation

> If $A^{1/A}=B^{1/B}=C^{1/C}$,  $A^{BC}+B^{AC}+C^{AB}=768$.  What is the value of $A^{1/A}$?

I tried solving this question but each time I get different answers like $3^{1/3}$,  3,  or   243.  What would be the correct method to solve this question?  Kindly elaborate your answer.The options are $81^{1/ABC}, 2^{1/2}, 27^{1/ABC},    
     9^{1/ABC}$.I've changed the question as the previous question was incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [Mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to typeset mathematical expressions. The equations in the title are confusing, the way they are.

Comment: I don't think this problem can be solved without numerical solvers.  Note that two of the variables must be equal.  If we assume $A=B$ and $C=tA=tB$, then the solution is $$(A,B,C)\approx (1.97791,1.97791,4.07190),$$ which gives $$A^{1/A}=B^{1/B}=C^{1/C}\approx 1.41175.$$  It involves solving for $t>0$ s.t. $$t^{\frac{1}{t-1}t^{\frac{t+1}{t-1}}}=243.$$  I don't see how Ak19's hint is useful.

Comment: This would have a nice solution if $A^{BC}+B^{CA}+C^{AB}=768$ instead.  In this case $t=2$ and $(A,B,C)=(2,2,4)$ is the unique solution with $A=B$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Yep! I agree, deleted my answer.

Comment: @AryanBhardwaj  What do you mean?  The book uses $768$, but you put $729$ here instead?

Comment: I think the book just gave you a wrong question.  For the parameter $729$, none of the options is the answer.  If the parameter were $768$ instead, $2^{1/2}$ would be the answer.  (You can reverse engineer and show that for $2^{1/2}$ to be the answer, the parameter would have to either be $48$, $768$, $196608$, or $12884901888$.)

Comment: Although,729 might be a misprint as there are several misprints in this book so kindly try it with 768 as I have discussed this question with my friends and teacher and they are too thinking that it should be 768.Please post the answer with 768 instead of 729.

Comment: Kindly post the answer of this question with 768 instead of 729.

Comment: I will post an answer if I could find an easy and clear way to show that $t^{\frac1{t-1}t^{\frac{t+1}{t-1}}}$ is a decreasing function for $t\in (0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$.   Perhaps there is another way without having to deal with this horrendous function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105976/discussion-between-aryan-bhardwaj-and-we-tutorial-school).

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Did you find and answer?

Comment: No...  Taking the derivative of $t^{\frac{1}{t-1}t^{\frac{t+1}{t-1}}}$ is horrendous.  I only know it is decreasing because of mathematica.  I can't prove it.

Comment: But since your problem is a multiple choice problem, and you can see that $k^{ABC}=\frac{768}{3}=256$, where $k=A^{1/A}$, then obviously $k=(256)^{1/(ABC)}$.  This means none of $81^{1/(ABC)}$, $27^{1/(ABC)}$, and $9^{1/(ABC)}$ is a valid answer.  Because $(A,B,C)=(2,2,4)$ gives you $k=\sqrt2$, it is the only possible answer.  But if this problem were a proof question, then so far, I have no proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}A^{BC}=\sum_{cyc}\left(A^{\frac{1}{A}}\right)^{ABC}=3\left(A^{\frac{1}{A}}\right)^{ABC},$$
which gives $$\left(A^{\frac{1}{A}}\right)^{ABC}=256,$$ which gives
$$A^{BC}=B^{AC}=C^{AB}=256.$$
Also, since the equation $x^{\frac{1}{x}}=k$ has two roots maximum,

we obtain that at least two numbers from $\{A,B,C\}$ are equal.

Let $C=B.$

Thus, we got the following system:
$$A^{B^2}=256$$ and
$$B^{AB}=256.$$
We have $$A=256^{\frac{1}{B^2}},$$ which gives
$$B^{B\cdot256^{\frac{1}{B^2}}}=256,$$ which gives $B=2$ or $B=1.029...$ or $B=2.474...$.

For $B=2$ we obtain: $$A^{\frac{1}{A}}=2^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt2.$$

Comment: I thought $748=256 \times 3$. You're using 243 instead of 256

Comment: @Plato The OP changed the parameter from $729=3\cdot 243$ to $768=3\cdot 256$. It is believed that the book where the problem came from made an error. See the edit history of the question, and the discussion under the question.